# How to make a lightning-progress-indicator fill the full screen width?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-progressindicator, lightning-progressstep

I have a simple `lightning-progress-indicator` in a Digital Experience that I don't know how to make stretch to the full width of the screen:

```
        <lightning-progress-indicator current-step={value} type="base">
            <template for:each={steps} for:item="step">
                <lightning-progress-step
                    label={step.label}
                    value={step.value}
                    key={step.value}
                    class="default-cursor"
                ></lightning-progress-step>
            </template>
        </lightning-progress-indicator>
```

It always shows at about 70% of the width whatever `width: 100%` styling I try to apply:

[image: example of not full width]

The SLDS [Progress Indicator](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-indicator/) documentation says:

> The slds-progress-bar accepts a range from 0% to 100%, and this percentage should be applied with inline styling to the div with class slds-progress-bar__value using JavaScript.

but no mention of width in the [lightning-progress-indicator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-progress-indicator) documentation?

Comment: 100% of the screen may not be 100% of the container of your lwc. It depends on the Digital Experience template, but most of them doesn't allow the 100%, like [this one](https://i.imgur.com/9kGzCfM.png) (an LWC can only fill the "column 1" box, it cannot *overflow* on those red marks). Does the progress-indicator already fill the 100% of its container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause here [salesforce-ux
/
design-system](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/blob/2cf575fdf80dc275987665b4674bdc68f1e3fe07/ui/components/progress-indicator/base/_index.scss#L11) in the SLDS CSS:

```
.slds-progress {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: auto;
  ...
}
```

We are overriding some styling already (this being a Digital Experience) so I'll change to `max-width: 100%`. Seems like an undocumented "feature" of the SLDS CSS.